# ruby hash.values is not working with built in method

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash

i tried almost everything but I am feeling cornered.

I have a CSV and reading a line from it:

```
CSV.foreach(file, quote_char: '"', col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true) { |line|

    newLine = []
    newLine = line.values #undefined method .values
    ...
}
```

line is aparently hash, because line['column_name'] is working fine and also line.to_a returns ["col","value","col2","value2",...]

please help, thank you!

Comment: What is `line.class`? Also `line.inspect`.

Comment: line.class is CSV::Row, line.inspect is starting like this: #<CSV::Row "col":"val" "col2":"val2"

Comment: So, not a `Hash`. Which makes the question invalid, right?

Comment: I never thought that it is not hash as it had similar syntax. I have done in ruby quite a lot but, you know, there is still much to learn for me. Thanks a lot, all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use #fields on the class CSV::Row

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not a regular hash, it is an instance of CSV::Row, see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) for the API

As you can see in the result of the following code the method values isn't there. Your solution of using line['column_name'] is fine.
You can get all the fields with the method fields without parameter.

```
CSV.parse(DATA, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true).each do |row|
    puts row.class
    puts row.methods - Object.methods
end

__END__
kId,kName,kURL
1,Google UK,http://google.co.uk
2,Yahoo UK,http://yahoo.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a CSV row which is part array and part hash and doesn't have the .values method available. Use .to_hash first and then you will be able to use .values. (Note that this will remove the field ordering and any duplicate fields)

```
newLine = line.to_hash.values
```